# Install VSTS extension fail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-extensions

We use one VSTS task "Install Extension" to install our private extension to marketplace in our build pipe line. At the frist time, the task can finish successfully and the extension is publish to marketplace, shared to the specific account and installed.
But when trigger another build and try to update the extension, we always get an error:

```
error: Error: Failed Request: Internal Server Error(500) - A task definition with id '963c1faa-ad05-43e5-aba0-9c7119270bf1', name 'CheckClassificationAll' and version '0.1.10' has already been uploaded by extension 'ExtensionTest-54327'. To upload the task, provide a different task id.
```

We don't understand why it prevent us to update a new one. In our extension, we have several build task and dashboard widget. It doesn't work even after the "ExtensionTest-54327" was been removed from marketplace.

Comment: What's the result after changing version and publishing? Update existing version of extension is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

It’s caused you have already publish your own extension to market place.

- If the extension don’t always need to update for the pipeline, you can upload extension in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers.
- If you should always need to update the extension for every time build, please make sure the extension’s version is updated for every time.

  Assume you have already upload your extension with 1.0.0, you should change the version to 1.0.1 in `vss-extension.json` file (as below) for next time. Else you will get the error message.

  ```
  {
  "manifestVersion": 1,
  "id": "fabrikam-build-extension",
  "name": "Fabrikam Build Tools",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  ...
  ```